# How to remove solr.admin.AdminHandlers from solrconfig.xml

Tags: solr

I'm planning to upgrade my solr from 5.X to 7.X.  When we upgrade from 5.X to 6.x I'm getting below exception.

> Error loading class 'solr.admin.AdminHandlers

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
```

I have seen workaround to clear that exception by commenting out below entry in Solr Config manually

```
<requestHandler name="/admin/" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
```

But I had 140+ configs in our cluster. Is there a way to do those changes over API. I cannot do it manually going one by one.